# How to prevent left join from returning multiple rows

Tags: sas

While using left join in SAS, the right side table have  duplicate IDs with different donations. Therefore, it returns several rows.
While i only want one row with the highest donated amount.

The code is as follows:

```
Create table x
As select T1.*,
T2. Donations

From xxx t1
Left join yy t2 on (t1.id = t2.id);
Quit;
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are  you able to sort results by DESC on t2.Donations and return top row?

Answer (score 1):

IN SAS follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/61486331/8227346

and in mysql
you can use partioning with ROW_NUMBER

```
CREATE TABLE x As select T1.*, T2.Donations 
From xxx t1 
LEFT JOIN
 
(

  SELECT * FROM 
    (
       SELECT
          *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY donated_amount DESC) rank
       FROM
        yy
    )
  
  WHERE
    rank = 1
)

t2
 ON (t1.id = t2.id);
```

More info can be found https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/rownumber-function-with-partition-by-clause-in-sql-server1

Answer (score 0):

You can either work with a subselect which selects only the highest donation for a given ID or you could do some pre work with SAS (which i prefer):

```
*Order ascending by ID and DONATIONS;
proc sort data=work.t2;
  by ID DONATIONS;
run;

*only retain the dataset with the highest DONATION per ID;
data work.HIGHEST_DONATIONS;
  set work.t2;
  by ID;

  if last.ID then output;
run;
```

I don't have SAS available right now but it should work.
Don't hesitate asking further questions. :)